# Getting and logging the selenium version used in a groovy project

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2

I'm using Selenium in my Groovy application as a Maven dependency. Now I'm looking for a way to log the used Selenium Version to the console.
I tried this:

```
  BuildInfo info = new BuildInfo();
  def infoString = info.toString();
```

But `infoString` only contains:

"Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'".

I also tried reading the version from the classpath of the project and though this works in a Java project in a groovy project the classpath no longer contains the used selenium version.

In a java project, the `infoString` also contains the used version, revision etc.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is this what you looking for? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574949/how-can-i-get-the-webdriver-version-during-testrun

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on how to get the Selenium version through code. I dont think there are any methods to do so.

But, the version is clearly mentioned in the CHANGELOG file that comes along with your Selenium installation.

You can read the version from this file. Below is the content of the log file:

> v2.43.0
>   ======= WebDriver:
>
> - Updating Native events to support Firefox 24, 31 and 32   * Add
>     note on stale element checks and a WebElement.................